# check if a tag element is empty in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I wonder if is possible to check if a tag element is empty, using React.
The tricky part is that the element is inside of an innerHTML from an external source.

For example:

```
<div ref={testRef} className="testBody" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: testHTML }} />
```

The innerHTML:

```
<div class="sectionHeader">
  <h1 class="sectionHeading">Primary Title</h1>
</div>
```

Inside the innerHTML is an "h1" I need to add a display none  if is empty, but for the entire **sectionHeader**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use the `:empty` pseudo class in your CSS. Whether it works is dependent on whether it's actually empty or just has white space. Share the `testHTML` if you want more help.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. Please, take a look of the innerHTML. The h1 is a nested element, but i need to display none the entire parent. Thanks!